# Using np.where() in a pandas calculation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to calculate a cumulative score of 3 columns, and have a 4th measure that takes conditions on the 3 columns and applies a number based on the columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), columns=list("abc"))
df['a'] * 1 + df['b'] * -1 + df['b'] * -1 + np.where((df['a'] > 0 and df['b'] > 0 and df['c'] > 0),
                                                 4,
                                                 0)
```

The error I get is `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

How would I be able to add a conditional statement (similar to a CASE statement in SQL) to a calculation?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do AND between two (or more) conditions on a DataFrame/Series you need to do it with `&` instead of `and`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), columns=list("abc"))
df['a'] * 1 + df['b'] * -1 + df['b'] * -1 + np.where((df['a'] > 0) & (df['b'] > 0) & (df['c'] > 0), 4, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I was wondering if the syntax on that is correct. I tried it on my non-dummy data, and I get the same ValueError.

Comment: You are correct, i messed up with the parentheses. You have to make sure each comparison is between parens. I updated my answer

Comment: thank you! i appreciate your help.